# Issue with Code Contract in c#

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I am facing a problem that I can not figure out.

Say I have two methods: `public void Method1(object obj)` in `ViewModel` class and `public void Method2(object obj)` in `Model` class.

`Method2` gets called from `Method1` using the instance of `Model` class(say, objM is the object of `Model` class and a member of `ViewModel` class).

```
class ViewModel
{
public void Methods1(object obj)
{
     if (!(
                        (      (false == this.HasSal)
                            && (typeof(Class1) == obj.GetType())
                          )
                    ||
                        (      (true == this.HasSal)
                            && (typeof(Class2) == obj.GetType())
                        )
                   ) 
                )
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("invalid obj");
            }
            Contract.EndContractBlock();
            objM.Method2(obj);
            .....
} 
}

class Model
{
public void Method2(object obj)
{
 Contract.Requires(
                    (      (false == this.HasSal)
                        && (typeof(Class1) == obj.GetType())
                    )
                ||
                    (      (true == this.HasSal)
                        && (typeof(Class2) == obj.GetType())
                    )

            );
    .....
    }
}
```

Now whenever I try to build the code, Visual studio produces following warning

```
Code contracts: Requires unproven
(
                    (      (false == this.HasSal)
                        && (typeof(Class1) == obj.GetType())
                    )
                ||
                    (      (true == this.HasSal)
                        && (typeof(Class2) == obj.GetType())
                    )

            )
```

Please suggest.

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951813/net-4-code-contracts-requires-unproven-source-null)

Comment: Please provide details on `HasSal` if possible. Is it a field or property? Is it readonly or [Pure]?

Answer (score 0):

As [rtrokzzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1866361/rtrokzzz) have given link to another SO question [.NET 4 Code Contracts: “requires unproven: source != null”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951813/net-4-code-contracts-requires-unproven-source-null) in comments

Solution for you is to add `Contract.Ensures` in `Method1()` and `Method2()`

Please note: I have not used `Code Contracts` but I believe from my understanding that code will be as

```
Contract.Ensures(obj != null);
```

### Update

```
Contract.Requires(obj != null);
```

Refer: [How to avoid “source !=null” when using Code Contracts and Linq To Sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069235/468718)

Comment: Refer the link here for some step-wise information on working with code contracts http://devjourney.com/blog/code-contracts-part-1-introduction/

Comment: This is another good link: [Better code with C# code contracts](http://www.develop.com/csharpcodecontracts).

Comment: My point is that I have made sure that if the condition mentioned in Code contract of Method2 is not met, then an exception is thrown from method1 before calling Method2 from Method 1. So Visual studio should not produce an warning for that condition. And Contract.Requires(obj != null) statement is already there in both method 1 and method 2. I did not mentioned about that because I thought that can not be an cause of concern.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the static checker will ever be able to verify your contract, because the type of `obj` isn't known until run-time - there is no guarantee that *only* objects of type  `Class1` or `Class2` will be passed to `Method1`.

It might be possible to prove this by adding additional contracts to methods that call `Method1`. If you include that code, I might be able to suggest a way to satisfy the static checker.

EDIT: Actually, there's another problem too. If `HasSal` is a public-setter property, then I'm not sure your contract can be verified - there's always a possibility that another thread could change the value of `HasSal` in between `Method1` being called and the method body being executed.

Comment: My point is that I have made sure that if the condition mentioned in Code contract of Method2 is not met, then an exception is thrown from method1 before calling Method2 from Method 1.So in case the condition is not satisfied, method2 is never going to be called. Is not that enough to satisfy that particular code contract in method2 ??

Comment: No, because by adding a `Contract.EndContractBlock();` to `Method1`, you're turning that `if` statement into an implicit `Contract.Requires` contract, too. And I think it's *that* one that the static checker is saying it can't prove, not the one in `Method2`. If that's what you want to achieve, then I think (but I haven't tested it myself) that removing the `Contract.EndContractBlock();` will remove the warning.

Comment: Actually, I think there's another problem, so I've edited the answer.

Comment: Commenting out Contract.EndContractBlock() is not helping

Comment: But issue with public setter can be the reason. I shall test it and let u know.